# Can't use QnAMakerClient to download Qna database content

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to use nuget Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Knowledge.QnAMaker to use QnAMakerClient and Knowledgebase.DownloadWithHttpMessagesAsync, but when I try to instantiate Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Knowledge.QnAMaker() the parameters are the abstract classes, so I don't know how I can use QnAMakerClient to download the contents of Body.QnaDocuments.

```
Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Knowledge.QnAMaker.QnAMakerClient z = new Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Knowledge.QnAMaker.QnAMakerClient(new ServiceClientCredentials(),HttpClient httpClient, bool disposeHttpClient);

var kb = z.Knowledgebase.DownloadWithHttpMessagesAsync("key", "test").Result;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@elise You can find one example on how to download the knowledgebase [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-dotnet-sdk-samples/blob/master/samples/QnAMaker/KnowledgebaseCrudSample.cs).

Essentially:

```
 var client = new QnAMakerClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(key)) { Endpoint = endpoint };
// Download the KB
Console.Write("Downloading KB...");
var kbData = await client.Knowledgebase.DownloadAsync(kbId, EnvironmentType.Prod);
Console.WriteLine("KB Downloaded. It has {0} QnAs.", kbData.QnaDocuments.Count);
```